# Read Japanese characters using FileInputStream

Tags: java, unicode, inputstream

I have java code running in PRODUCTION and we support upload of properties file to be uploaded. The code on server is

```
Properties props = new Properties();
File resourceBundle = new File("<The client path>");
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(resourceBundle);
props.load(inStream);
```

This does not work for Japanese and Chinese characters like  详细信息.

If we convert this to Unicode like \u30A2\u30B8\u30A2/\u30E4\u30AF\u30FC\u30C4\u30AF, it works.

Without doing code changes how can i make it to work without using unicode characters ?

NOTE: The InputStreamReader  will work, but due to lack to time, need a solution.

Comment: The tool `native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 ...` of the JDK does u-escaping as you did. It can convert back too. Otherwise there is no switch, as properties are in ISO-8859-1. In java 9 first UTF-8 is attempted.

Comment: `props.load(new InputStreamReader(inStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));` and you should be fine

Comment: The standard Java properties are iso-8859-1, so technically is a mistake to read them as UTF-8. It is more convenient, but they are not standard anymore.  JDK 9 added UTF-8 support, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#JSINT-GUID-974CF488-23E8-4963-A322-82006A7A14C7. But if not, diginoise's answer is the correct one.